# Variable not working inside IN clause

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, postgresql

This code is written in Excel2010 VBA and queries PostGreSQL tables

I have the following code in VBA that creates a variable that I would like to use in my SQL query, but I cannot get the SQL query to accept the VBA variable using the IN clause

This code creates the variable I want to use and works fine. It allows me to select specific cells I need to query

```
Dim StaffID As Range
Dim ID As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim SelectedID As String

'Count number of rows to search
LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next    'if only 1 row

'Store Data from here
Set StaffID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & LR)

'Loop through each cell in Range and look for any character in column A
'then store offset cell value using comma delimiter
For Each ID In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LR).Cells
    If ID.Value > 0 Then
        SelectedID = SelectedID & "," & ID.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
Next ID

'Remove first delimiter from string (,)
 SelectedID = Right(SelectedID, Len(SelectedID) - 1)
```

OUTPUT EXAMPLE of SelectedID = 6,7,8,6452

I now want to add this to my query using the IN clause, but it just doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution or workaround.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim t As String
t = "SELECT DISTINCT s.entity_id, u.login_name, s.role " _
            & "FROM staff s INNER JOIN user u ON s.entity_id=u.staff_id " _
            & "WHERE u.staff_id IN (SelectedID) " _

Set rs = conn.Execute(t)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're putting the string 'SelectedID' directly into your query. You'll need something like this in your VBA:

```
t = "SELECT DISTINCT s.entity_id, u.login_name, s.role " _
            & "FROM staff s INNER JOIN user u ON s.entity_id=u.staff_id " _
            & "WHERE u.staff_id IN (" & SelectedID & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rows.Count` should be fully qualified and `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` and fully qualifying will make your code read better.

```
Function getSelectedIDSQL() As String
    Dim ID As Range, StaffID As Range
    Dim SelectedID As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each ID In .Range("A2" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If ID.Value > 0 Then SelectedID = SelectedID & "," & ID.Offset(, 1).Value
        Next
    End With

    If Len(SelectedID) Then getSelectedIDSQL = Right(SelectedID, Len(SelectedID) - 1)

End Function
```